# Prove that there is no $d > 0$ and no point $P$ such that $PA = \sqrt{(x^2 + d)}$ , $PB = \sqrt{(y^2 + d)}$ and $PC = \sqrt{(z^2 + d)}$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $O$ is a point in the plane of $\triangle ABC$ with $OA = x, OB = y$ and $OC = z$. Prove that there is no $d > 0$ and no point $P$ such that $PA = \sqrt{(x^2 + d)}$ , $PB = \sqrt{(y^2 + d)}$ and $PC = \sqrt{(z^2 + d)}$.

**What I Tried**:- I have no idea how to show this in general, it looks very tough.

I tried some small examples, like if I would take $OA = 5$ , $OB = 6$ , $OC = 4$ , then at first I put $d = 11$ so $PA = 6$ , $PB = \sqrt{47}$ , $PC = 3\sqrt{3}$. And with Geogebra, I confirmed and am almost sure, that no such point $P$ exist (which also, isn't very rigorous). This is not a rigorous approach, and I still need to prove it, along with the general case, for which I have no idea.

Can someone help me how to do this? I am not finding any clue how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $O$ and $P$ be two (distinct) points in the plane. We claim that the set $S$ of all points $X$ such that $PX^2 - OX^2 = d$ is a line. This implies that no triangle can be formed from points in $S$, proving the result.
If you take $O = (0,0)$ and $P=(a,0)$, then for $X=(x,y)$,
$$PX^2-OX^2 = (x-a)^2+y^2-x^2-y^2=a^2-2ax.$$
Setting this as a constant $d$ gives a line, completing the proof.

Comment: Got it, actually there was a problem before this in my book which showed that this equation will be a straight line, and I didn't expect that can be used here also.